# How to get attributes of collection and put in other array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections, fullcalendar

I'm need to get atributes of "date", "id", "inicial" and "final" to put in as a object in other array

I'm try using lodash, but i still don't work

```
let all = [
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 1,
        inicial: "10:00",
        final: "11:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 1,
    date: "17-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 2,
        inicial: "12:00",
        final: "13:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 2,
    date: "18-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 3,
        inicial: "10:00",
        final: "11:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 3,
    date: "19-08-1993"
  }
];
 let events = [{}]
```

I expected this result:

```
events: [
{id: "value_of_id_prof", title: "{{value_of_inicial}}", start: "value_of_date"},
{the_result_for_each_object_of_all},
{...},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
let all = [{
    horas: [{
      id_prof: 1,
      inicial: "10:00",
      final: "11:00"
    }],
    id: 1,
    date: "17-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [{
      id_prof: 2,
      inicial: "12:00",
      final: "13:00"
    }],
    id: 2,
    date: "18-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [{
      id_prof: 3,
      inicial: "10:00",
      final: "11:00"
    }],
    id: 3,
    date: "19-08-1993"
  }
];

const events = all.map(allObj => {
  return {
    id: allObj.id,
    title: allObj.horas[0].inicial,
    start: allObj.date
  };
});

console.log(events);
```

As long as the `horas` array will only ever have one object in, this will work.

Comment: Small typo - data should be date.

Comment: Wonderful, is exactly what i looking. Really glad for your answer!!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```js
let all = [
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 1,
        inicial: "10:00",
        final: "11:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 1,
    date: "17-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 2,
        inicial: "12:00",
        final: "13:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 2,
    date: "18-08-1993"
  },
  {
    horas: [
      {
        id_prof: 3,
        inicial: "10:00",
        final: "11:00"
      }
    ],
    id: 3,
    date: "19-08-1993"
  }
];
 let events = all.map(x => ({id:x.id, date:x.date, inicial:x.horas[0].inicial, final:x.horas[0].final}))
 console.log(events)
```

Horas should really be an object if you want to reduce it to just one inicial and final.

Also, you should post what you have tried already, always helps.

Comment: thanks Anton!! You're right, i read mt question again and see i wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   const all = [
     {
       horas: [
         {
           id_prof: 1,
           inicial: '10:00',
           final: '11:00',
         },
       ],
       id: 1,
       date: '17-08-1993',
     },
     {
       horas: [
         {
           id_prof: 2,
           inicial: '12:00',
           final: '13:00',
         },
       ],
       id: 2,
       date: '18-08-1993',
     },
     {
       horas: [
         {
           id_prof: 3,
           inicial: '10:00',
           final: '11:00',
         },
       ],
       id: 3,
       date: '19-08-1993',
     },
   ];
   
   const result = all.map((r) => {
     const obj = { id: r.id, date: r.date, inicial: r.horas[0].inicial };
     return obj;
   });
   console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you so much! It's what i need! God bless you =)

Comment: Happy to help :)